# Excel VBA: Filter, cut, and paste to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

1st sheet named `src` while the 2nd one is `dst` which is an empty sheet at the moment.

My plan is to filter string `x` in column B, cut it and paste it to 2nd sheet `dst`

[image]

**VBA code**

```
Sub filter_copy_paste()

With Sheets("src")
    .Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="x"
    With .AutoFilter.Range
        With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
            .Copy
            With Sheets("dst")
                .Paste
                .[A1].Select
            End With
        End With
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

However, there is an error when I run it and when I hit `Debug`, it highlights line number 5 which is `With .AutoFilter.Range`

[image]

What wrong in this code and what should I do to fix it?

**Desired output in 1st sheet `src`**

[image]

**Desired output in 2nd sheet `dst`**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter

You can see that autofilter does not return a range.

It's the equivalent of filtering using the Excel functionality. Which means that you will have to select this subset before moving this data.

Answer (score 0):

### AutoFilter 'Cut/Paste'

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

' If you already have the headers in "dst".
Sub filter_copy_paste()

    With Worksheets("src")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then
            .AutoFilterMode = False
        End If
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        rng.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="x"
        Dim cRng As Range
        On Error Resume Next
        Set cRng = rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1) _
                      .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
        On Error GoTo 0
        If cRng Is Nothing Then
            GoTo showAll
        End If
        Dim pRng As Range
        Set pRng = Worksheets("dst").Range("A2")
        'With pRng
        '    .EntireRow.Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1).Clear
        'End With
        cRng.Copy Destination:=pRng
        cRng.Delete
showAll:
        .ShowAllData
    End With

End Sub

' If you don't have the headers in "dst".
Sub filter_copy_pastenh()

    With Worksheets("src")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then
            .AutoFilterMode = False
        End If
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        rng.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="x"
        Dim cRng As Range
        On Error Resume Next
        Set cRng = rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1) _
                      .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
        On Error GoTo 0
        If cRng Is Nothing Then
            GoTo showAll
        End If
        Dim pRng As Range
        Set pRng = Worksheets("dst").Range("A1")
        'pRng.Worksheet.Cells.Clear
        Union(rng.Rows(1).EntireRow, cRng).Copy Destination:=pRng
        cRng.Delete
showAll:
        .ShowAllData
    End With

End Sub
```